# Get value from complicate array having object

Tags: php

```
CoinGate\Merchant\Order Object
(
    [order:CoinGate\Merchant\Order:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 97977
            [status] => new
            [do_not_convert] => 
            [price_currency] => USD
            [price_amount] => 1200.0
            [lightning_network] => 
            [receive_currency] => EUR
            [receive_amount] => 
            [created_at] => 2018-07-03T05:53:43+00:00
            [order_id] => 459469
            [payment_url] => https://sandbox.coingate.com/invoice/94423345-1a1a-4895-a08e-98793777b0d0
            [token] => x5Yrx5mmku8nkyK2ShVvbCuiJfasoxsNBtxZ27Ra
        )

)
```

This is response of request but i am facing to get values from such array. I need to get payment_url from such array.

Comment: it already says `private` so you can't actually directly point to it, maybe your object has its own getter functions to get what you want

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether you want to post an array containing, what looks to be, an authorisation token here.. I suspect not.

Answer (score 1):

In a [`Order.php`](https://github.com/coingate/coingate-php/blob/master/lib/Merchant/Order.php) file there's a magic `__get` method. So, you should use it to get the property you need:

```
// suppose $response is the value you `var_dump`ed in a question.
echo $response->payment_url;   // same for other properties: $response->status
```

Comment: Feel free to __accept__ an answer if it helped to solve your problem. And in your other questions __too__.

Answer (score 0):

[get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) function in PHP convert object to array. Consider you are having this object in variable `$x`, then you should do like:

```
$y = get_object_vars($x);
echo $y['payment_url'];
```

Comment: This is not working it return 'Undefined index: order'

Comment: Try directly as `$y['payment_url']`